# How can I add folders in my .juliarc folder for running programs in Julia?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to setup the julia code here: https://github.com/SMuscimol/multiDchaos.
Although I'm not sure how to include the repositories "RateNet", "AdaptiveNet" and "MyTools" in my .juliarc.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175314/where-is-juliarc-the-julia-startup-file/52175490#52175490), .juliarc files are deprecated, and you should be modifying the startup.jl file instead. The multiDchaos readme should probably be updated accordingly – it looks like it initially was developed on Julia 0.7, when .juliarc files were still around.

As to how you can add the local packages, you can use Julia's built-in package manager. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571690/how-do-i-add-a-local-project-to-the-import-path-in-julia). Cheers and best of luck!