# Loading Module in Julia

Tags: module, julia

i'm having some trouble loading module in Julia. I have to module that i cant load in my main file.

So my code (i'm trying to make an octree) look like this:

```
module Node
    
    export node, contains, intersect
    
    mutable struct node
        x::Float64
        y::Float64
        z::Float64
        m::Float64 
        node(x,y,z) = new(x,y,z,0)
    end
    
end # module
```

and my other module:

```
module Tree
        
    include("Node.jl")
    using .Node
        
    export tree, insert!, subdivide!
        
    mutable struct tree
            
        capacity::Int64
        node::node
        divided::Bool
        
        tree(capacity, node) = new(capacity, node, false)
    end
end
```

My problem is when i try to import the module in my main file using something like that:

```
include("Node.jl")
using .Node
include("Tree.jl")
using .Tree
    
plop=node(0,0,0)
plip=tree(1,plop)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type node to an object of type Main.Tree.Node.node
```

I understand its due to the `using .Node` in my tree module which conflict with the same import in the main file but i'm unable to find a workaround.

One solution would probably be to put everything in the same module but i would like to keep thing separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you actually just put the two modules in the same module. Or to be more precise, you have a module `Node` and a module `Tree` with a submodule `Node` in it, thus the `Main.Tree.Node.node`. This happens because you use `include("Node.jl")` within your `Tree` module. The include function works as if it copied the text in the `Node.jl` file and pasted it into the `Tree.jl` file. Thus, to use the `Node` module within `Tree` without creating a submodule you have to add it.

So, I'd recommend you to generate a package for both the `Node` and `Tree` modules. This is done by

```
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.generate("Node")
  Generating  project Node:
    Node/Project.toml
    Node/src/Node.jl
```

and then copy your `Node.jl` and `Tree.jl` files to replace the ones that were created.
Then you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571690/how-do-i-add-a-local-project-to-the-import-path-in-julia) that tells you how to add a local package.

To sum it up you need to

```
julia> Pkg.develop(path="/Path/to/Node")
julia> Pkg.develop(path="/Path/to/Tree")
```

then your `/Path/to/Tree/src/Tree.jl` looks like

```
module Tree
    using Node
    [...]
end
```

and to run your code you can type

```
julia> using Node, Tree
julia> plop=node(0,0,0)
node(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
julia> plip=tree(1,plop)
tree(1, node(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), false)
```

Note that it will probably tell you that Tree does not have Node in its dependencies. To solve that you might want to have a look at the documentation of [`Pkg.jl`](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/).

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Just a follow up question. what is the best practice ? creating a pkg or import a module ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question, a module is in a certain way a package in Julia, so to import a module you first have to create it. A good instruction is [Creating Packages](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/). Anyways, if `Node` and `Tree` are not too different from each other, I'd suggest you put them both in the same package and develop only one.

Comment: yes its more of the second part i was thinking. should i keep one concept = one module or group things together. but you already answer ! thx for your help